# Incorrect output in SQL partition query

Tags: sql

I have a table with the initial values as:

```
+---------------------------------------+
| Entity  Country   Month_No.   Reports |
+---------------------------------------+
| FC        US         10          2    |
| FC        US         10          3    |
| FC        GER        10          4    |
| FC        GER        10          7    |
| FC        US         11          5    |
| FC        GER        11          8    |
+---------------------------------------+
```

I tried running a query on this table using this code:

```
SELECT entity, country, mnth, SUM(reports) OVER (PARTITION BY mnth) FROM practice1;
```

The output that I got from this code was:

```
+---------------------------------------+
| Entity  Country   Month_No.   Reports |
+---------------------------------------+
| FC        US         10          16   |
| FC        US         10          16   |
| FC        GER        10          16   |
| FC        GER        10          16   |
| FC        US         11          13   |
| FC        GER        11          13   |
+---------------------------------------+
```

The expected output should be like this:

```
+---------------------------------------+
| Entity  Country   Month_No.   Reports |
+---------------------------------------+
| FC        US         10          5    |
| FC        GER        10          11   |
| FC        US         11          5    |
| FC        GER        11          8    |
+---------------------------------------+
```

How do I get this as output?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem can be solved with a simple `group by`:

```
SELECT entity, country, mnth, SUM(reports) 
FROM practice1
GROUP BY entity, country, mnth
```

Answer (score 1):

You're summing reports by month, not by entity, country, and month. Adding entity and country to the `partition by` clause gets you the numbers you want, but now there are some duplicate rows because there are multiple rows with the same entity, country, and month. You can add `distinct` to get rid of those.

```
SELECT distinct entity, country, mnth, 
    SUM(reports) OVER (PARTITION BY entity, country, mnth)
FROM practice1;
```

Do you need to use `partition by`? Seems like you're better off just using `group by`.

```
SELECT entity, country, mnth, SUM(reports)
FROM practice1;
GROUP BY entity, country, mnth
```

Comment: SO shall I do it like this? 

SELECT entity, country, mnth, SUM(reports) OVER (PARTITION BY entity, country, mnth) FROM practice1;